# Not able to use @Autowired with @Mock while creating unit test cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I have a service say `MainService` and it has few managers which are initialised with `@Autowired`, and it is using some external service which are also `@Autowired`.

My purpose is to create unit test cases so that I can access the inmemory DB with managers, and want to mock the external service.

Now problem which I am facing is if I use `@Autowired` in my unit test and use `@Mock` for external services, then it doesn't use mock methods, Instead it uses the actual implementation. If I do `@InjectMocks` then it doesn't pick the data from repo as it doesn't find the respective dependencies for managers, and if I use `@Autowired` and `@InjectMocks` together it still not being able to use the Mocks.

Something like this

```
@Service
public class MainService extends AbstractService
{
  @Autowired
  Manager1 manager1;

  @Autowired
  Manager2 manager2;

  @Autowired
  Manager3 manager3;

@Trace(dispatcher = true)
public void mainMethod(int data)
{
 int data1 = manager1.getData(int xyz);\\ getting data from DAO
 int data2 = manager1.getData(int xyz);\\ getting data from DAO
 int data3 = manager1.getData(int xyz);\\ getting data from 
                                        \\External Service
    }

  }
```

Now the test case I am writing is

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestClass {

  @InjectMocks
  @Autowired  
  MainService service;

  @Autowired
  RepoForManager1 repoManager1;

  @Autowired
  RepoForManager2 repoManager2;

  @Mock
  Manager3 manager3;

  @Before
  public void initTest()
  {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      int dataFirst=1;
      int dataSecond =2;
      int dataThird=3;
      int dataForMethod=4;
      repoManager1.save(dataFirst); 
      repoManager2.save(dataSecond);
     }

   @Test
      public void testMethod()
      { 

         Mockito.when(manager3.getData(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(dataThird);
         service.mainMethod(dataForMethod);
       }
 }
```

This is a replication of the actual service, when I debug the test I found that the mock is not being used, its using actual implementation, and when I removed `@Autowired` from `MainService` then it only execute the mocked method.

Comment: You cannot auto wire something and inject mocks. You are using Spring Boot so instead of `@Mock` use `@MockBean` which will do all that for you. Remove the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` as that isn't needed anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum, he can, but he will need to run test in AppContext with custom BeanFactory that is aware of mocks he created.

Comment: No he doesn't, Spring Boot takes care of that.

Comment: Technically, you could also call Mockito manually and let it handle the mocking, but what for, as Spring can do it perfectly fine. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Field Injection(using `@Autowired` on class variables) use Constructor Injection. This way you can initialize your MainService class with some mocks and some real Implementations. Something like this

```
    @Service
    public class MainService extends AbstractService
    {

      private final Manager1 manager1;

      private final Manager2 manager2;

      private final SomeExternalService externalService;

       @Autowired
       public MainService(Manager1 manager1, Manager2 manager2, SomeExternalService externalService) 

            this.manager1= manager1;
            this.manager2= manager2;
            this.externalService = externalService;
    }
            ........................
   }
```

From your test class don't Autowire MainService. Just Autowire Manager1 and Manager2 and Create Mock for SomeExternalService(and initialize it). And then create instance of MainService using constructor.

```
    public class TestClass {

          MainService service;

          @Autowired
          RepoForManager1 repoManager1;

          @Autowired
          RepoForManager2 repoManager2;

          @Mock
          SomeExternalService externalService;

          @Before
          public void setUp(){
           service = new MainService(repoManager1, repoManager2, externalService);
          }
   }
```

Comment: Do I need to create an object using this constructor, for accessing the method?, or else how can i access the method which I need to call                          service.mainMethod(dataForMethod); its giving error

Comment: @sonendersingh, in test you will need to create service via constructor.

Comment: Problem is resolved with this approach, now I am able to use both real and mock. thanks :)

Comment: cheers. Here is a very good article about Construction and Field Injection. http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/.  Do accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Mockito, you need Annotate your `TestClass` with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Then for the `@AutoWired` in the `TestClass` for `repoManager1`, `repoManger2`. Annotate them with `@Mock` instead of `@Autowired`, as you want to mock them with Mockito.

I have not used the SpringRunner myself, but from a quick read, I can see that it is used mostly for Integration Test, where you want to load the SpringContext..etc.

Also `@ActiveProfiles("test")` is mostly used for Integration Test, where you want to load the spring context, with the 'test' profile properties.